# Sensor to detect flip

Tags: arduino, sensor

What would be an appropriate sensor to use with arduino lilypad to detect movement of card. The sensor will be attached to one side(top) of the card, when the card is flipped i.e when sensor faces down, then I should be able to detect it. Please help. The card would be held in hand just like a visiting card( a bit thick ). Imagine reading 1 side of card then we turn it other side to view more. So I must know if the user has turned over the card.

Comment: What size is the card? Where will the sensor be - under or over? What positional variation between flips? Is the card moving on a conveyor or sitting on a table? Please edit your question to explain the application and add a sketch, if possible.

Comment: Tilt switch / accelerometer is the easy solution, but if you have a lot of cards it might be better to put the sensor in the table and put a magnet in the card.

Comment: After 3 years I still wonder, what this person might have though before down voting this question.. lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a [tilt switch](https://www.adafruit.com/products/173)? It gives a true-or-false output only, which seems to do the trick unless of course the "card" you mean is very thin.

Comment: Good one, had a quick view, this one might help, will give it a try

Comment: will this be good? http://www.amazon.in/Simple-Labs-Triple-Axis-Accelerometer/dp/B00K2Z3140?tag=googinhydr18418-21&tag=googinkenshoo-21&ascsubtag=051c593a-55ea-4157-854e-1b9a16a5a410#Ask

Comment: definitely, tho it's different from what I mentioned in my answer, as it's a digital accelerometer (requires an I2C bus connection to your Arduino, but perfectly doable). IMHO it's a bit overkill for such a simple application

Answer (score 0):

A light sensor on one side of the card.